# linux recursive copy specified files doesn't work

Tags: regex, linux, macos, terminal

I want to recursive copy all the files which start with letters in directory data to directory test. So I wrote this:

```
find data -type f -exec grep '^[a-z]' {} \; -exec cp -f {} ./test \;
```

However, it also matched other files.

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command isn't executing `grep` on filenames, but rather on *the contents of those files*.

You say:

> copy all the files which start with letters in directory

which would use a `find` command that's matching filenames which requires the `-name` option.  For example,

```
find data -type f -name '[a-z]*'
```

By using the `-exec` option to find, instead you're executing the provided command (`grep '^[a-z]' {}`) on every file that `find` finds in the data directory since there is no filename matching clause (`-name`).

The command you likely want is:

```
find data -type f -name '[a-z]*' -exec cp -f {} ./test \;
```